# Python unc - windows mapped drive equivelency

Tags: python, windows, unc

is there a way to check if a unc path is the same paths as the mapped drive?

the only way i can think of is going through every drive letter and seeing if the contents of the folder match.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you could use, for example, `p = pathlib.Path('Z:').resolve()`. This should give you the underlying UNC path for a mapped Z: drive.

Comment: I'm using maya so I can't cause it comes with 2.4. So far I've come up with checking with os.stat as a better solution